# Remove recovery partitions on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

Windows 10 is doing this to my SSD:

[image: SSD Partitions]

I want to remove those three partitions (581MB, 13.23GB and 1.14GB) after the **OS (C:)** to reclaim the space (since the disk is only 128GB and wasting 14GB doesn't feel right with me) but Windows 10's Disk Management tool does not let me delete them. This is understandable since after all, they are marked as "Recovery Partition" but I don't need or want recovery: if there is a problem, I will just reinstall Windows from scratch (i.e. USB drive). Some partitions might be coming from the manufacturer (Dell, in my case).

Is there a way to reclaim the space?

Comment: Only with 3rd party tools.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Could you give me the name of the tool?

Comment: Macrium Reflect (free) should do it and many others as well, even a Linux live session using Gparted or other. Just make sure that you disable Windows Fast Startup (and have backups, obviously) before trying whatever has been suggest.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try.

Comment: It would be wise to decrypt first… and also have a solid up to date backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, that's what Macrium Reflect was for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diskpart can delete any type of partition with the `override` parameter.

The diskpart commands to use (very carefully) are (where `#` is to be substituted):

```
list disk
select disk #
list partition
select partition #
delete partition override
exit
```

Reference:
[DiskPart Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766465(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: That's not always sufficient. Write protection may still prevent deletion. Hence, one must use `ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY` once the correct disk is selected (i.e after `SELECT DISK #`) prior to try to delete the partition.